# How to Call the json webservice in the background?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application in which I have a settings page, where I need to edit each entity.  For that when the user selects each entity we will go to a separate page and edit there and come back.  I need to update the edited value by calling the service in background, but I need to come back to main view as soon as I edit the value.  So I am using the GCD way.

```
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue_, ^{
            [self update];
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            });
        });
```

But sometimes I get the crashes like `ASHTTPheaders` `didreciveresponseheaders`,and `ASHTTprequest reportFailure`.  Can anybody point me in the right direction to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to happen immediately after the app goes to the background, you can probably use [-[UIApplication beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html). That should work as long as the task doesn't take too long.